# Mac OS X Hot Corners: run a custom AppleScript?

Tags: macos, system-preferences

Is there a way to run a custom AppleScript or any other custom application using the "Hot Corners" of Mac OS X?

The default system settings list a number of actions (e.g. Launchpad, Mission Control, Desktop, etc.), but nothing that would allow me to launch a custom app. Maybe there's a way to "redirect" one of those to do just that?